# How to send notifications using Azure Notification Hub with PHP?

Tags: php, azure, push-notification, azure-eventhub

I am trying to send the notification to my azure notification hub using PHP. I am using [these](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs-samples/tree/master/notificationhubs-rest-php) 2 classes to send out the notifications.
When I try to send the notifications, I see this error

```
{ "message": "Error sending notificaiton: 400 msg: \r\n\r\n\r\n

Bad Request

\r\n
HTTP Error 400. The request is badly formed.
```

My function is

```
public function sendNotificationHub() {


        $hub    =   new \App\Helpers\NotificationHub('connection string', 'central US');
        $message = '{"data":{"message":"Hello from PHP!"}}';

        $notification   =   new \App\Helpers\Notfication("gcm", $message);

        $hub->sendNotification($notification, null);
    }
```

Comment: 400 clearly indicate that the request is malformed (for example, not valid routing headers, not valid content-type, message exceeds size, bad message format). Is your hub name is "Central US"? Please check this blog for reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-php-push-notification-tutorial

Comment: This was a silly mistake. Changed the hub name to my actual one and everything is working now. Thanks

Comment: Glad to know it works, I would ask you to Accept this as an answer so that this could be a help to everyone who have the same ASK.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

400 clearly indicate that the request is malformed (for example, not valid routing headers, not valid content-type, message exceeds size, bad message format).

Is your hub name is "Central US"? Please check this blog for reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/notification-hubs-php-push-notification-tutorial

See if it helps.